# The Blog Overflow "No Blog" page has an extra <a> HTML tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog-overflow

The HTML for http://blogoverflow.com/no-blog-yet.html seems to have an extra tag.

[image]

"There is a dedicated" is a link of its own, separated from "chat room," but it doesn't have any `href` associated with it. So it's styled like a link, but doesn't actually point anywhere.

It looks like this is the code for it:

```
<p>
    <a>There is a dedicated
    <a href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs">chat room</a>
    to help you get started and run your community blog.  Feel free to drop in and say hi!
</p>
```

So either that first `<a>` tag isn't meant to be there, or it needs the second's `href` and the second one shouldn't be there.

It's certainly not a big deal, but it's definitely unexpected behavior to not be able to click anywhere on that "link."

For what it's worth, I'm on IE 11, and it's automatically closing that first `<a>` before opening the next one. I don't know if other browsers handle that differently, if anyone tries to repro it.

Comment: I think only the "chat room" is meant to be a link, that first `<a>` is a mistake. Plus, the room is now frozen so it's actually a dead link as it's not possible to say "hi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that we actually had an improperly closed `<a>` tag on the line before. One little `<a/>` instead of `</a>` and suddenly browsers are trying to compensate. :)

Fixed now. Thanks!